# Historical MovableType (2.x) Downloads?

Tags: download, package, movabletype

Not really a programming question, but I can't think of anywhere else to ask. Is there a reasonable way to get my hands on the source package for MovableType 2.x? (v2.6 to be specific.) That's [circa 2003](http://www.movabletype.com/blog/2003/02/version-26-released.html) apparently.

I'm trying to work with an old archived blog and it would be extremely helpful to run some diffs against the clean source. I can't find any documentation for that era online to refer to either, so right now I'm working blind.

I'm vaguely aware of an "ownership change" in MT's history but I'm ignorant of any details that might explain the absence of historical versions on the internet. Are there resources still available for MT from that long ago? Has my google-fu simply failed me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous versions are archived [here](http://www.movabletype.org/downloads/archives/). (As per usual, that's not documented anyplace in particular; you just have to know about it, so stash that.)

The archive directory does *not* include the current versions at any given time. For those, go up a directory, and look in /stable, or just grab them from the on-site download links, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Su mentioned to you the URL where some of the previous versions are available for download.

If you need specifically v2.6, that version is not there (there it is v2.661), but I could provide it to you via email. In case you still need it get in touch.